# Change Notification icon and App name on front screen iOS

Tags: xcode, ios7, notifications, ios8, localnotification

In my app i need to change the Notification icon and its header name is it possible to change that on main screen. please see the attached image for more info :

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The icon and the header name are read from the Application Bundle and I don't believe you can change these only on the main screen.

The icon is a resized version of the Application icon and the header is the same text as the Application Name.